# Xcode Error Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

DataModelCompile /Users/maxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pectopatop-axonkvxdjwugklfuanzpglrsyquj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pectopatop.app/XMPPRoster.mom Pectopatop/../../Libraries/XMPPFramework/Extensions/Roster/CoreDataStorage/XMPPRoster.xcdatamodel
    cd /Users/maxxx/ios/Pectopatop
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc -XD_MOMC_SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphonesimulator -MOMC_PLATFORMS iphoneos /Users/maxxx/ios/Pectopatop/Pectopatop/../../Libraries/XMPPFramework/Extensions/Roster/CoreDataStorage/XMPPRoster.xcdatamodel /Users/maxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pectopatop-axonkvxdjwugklfuanzpglrsyquj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pectopatop.app/XMPPRoster.mom

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc failed with exit code 1

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049106/xcode-error-command-developer-usr-bin-momc-failed-with-exit-code-6

Answer (score 2):

For future problems, I had this and it was due to the fact that I set the same outlet for two objects.

Comment: Yeah!!!!...That actually helped a lot....In my case the error is coming, if I am making the connection to another viewController using segue and trying to present that as popover.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you are still referencing derived data that no longer exists.

remove all *.xcdatamodel directories that are not displayed in XCode from your *.xcdatamodelid directory. These directories appear after *.xcdatamodel renaming in XCode.

Removing is done simply in Terminal or by Show package contents menu in Finder.

However, to get a clearer picture you could:

Go to Build->Build Results or hit shift-command-B. There's an icon on the far right of the error message that looks like a bunch of horizontal lines. Click that or select "all messages".

If you still do not understand you could:

```
cd /var/log
cat system.log
```

Comment: It is not solution. I have one file in .xcdatamodeld directory and delete it. No differences.

Answer (score 0):

One more reason could be: Link binary with Libraries might have files which do not exist on the disk.

Regards,
Anand Choubey

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically what I've done to resolve this problem is that I've made a screenshots of my former, not functioning data model, deleted it from project to the trash.. and created it again from the beginning with the same attributes and names that I had before. When I built the app again, no error anymore.

hope this helps, I did it within 5 minutes with 2 entities.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a corrupted framework that caused this ( PaddleMas 1.18 for me)

Try removing each of your frameworks that you are using and seeing if this problem goes away permanently.  I was able to make this error go away temporarily by using the clean build folder command ( press alt and go to product menu and select `clean build folder` )

The permanent fix has been to remove the offending framework but I have seen others with corrupted images also causing this.

Hope this helps!